# String #define returns a random integer

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, c-strings

As far as I know `#define` is just a string replacement and it's not a variable, so it doesn't have any memory address or something.

Suppose this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ONE "a"

main() {
    printf("the number is: %d\n", ONE);
}
```

Then when I compile and run this program, I get a *random* string each time:

> the number is: 8179551
>
> the number is: 21127007
>
> the number is: 57114463
>
> ...

If the `#define` doesn't have any memory address, then what's this value and why it's changed every time?

Comment: You're printing the address of a string.  (Try the same printf using "a" instead of ONE -- you'll get the same result.)

Comment: The second half of the answer is that your system is using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Comment: And your program invokes undefined behavior by passing a pointer to `printf` with a `%d` format, so you should avoid doing it on purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code

```
printf("the number is: %d\n", ONE);
```

is equivalent to

```
printf("the number is: %d\n", "a");
```

In fact you are printing the address of the string `"a"` as a decimal.

And you are getting random value in each execution that's because the address of `"a"` is got random address in each execution

The string `"a"` is a literal string and it's stored in the read only memory. The `printf` is printing the address of this memory

Comment: Then it should be changed every time? What you mean by `printing the address of the string`?

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani the string "a" is a literal string and it's stored in the read only memory. The printf is printing the address of this memory

Comment: Strange. I didn't know that the strings also stored in the memory! Sorry I'm newbie.

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani what are you trying to do?

Comment: @MOHAMED Nothing complex, I just want to know the difference between `#define` and constants in `C` so I wrote this code to see. Thank you man.

Comment: Why does this answer get upvoted? It's dead wrong. It's undefined behavior because the format specification doesn't match the type of argument (int versus char *).

Comment: @jens proof from standard?

Comment: @jens I see your answer I check

Comment: @Jens: I voted the answer down because it fails to advise the reader about the improper code. However, the answer is likely not incorrect; the C implementation in this case likely does print the address of the string as a decimal. The fact that the C standard does not define something does not mean it does not occur. In that regard, this answer is just bad, not wrong. It may be wrong in stating that the string is stored in read-only memory, but that could be true as well.

Answer (score 1):

MOHAMED is right, you printing the adress of a string

what you what to do this

```
#define ONE 'a'
```

everything between two `'`'s  are characters, only one character is allowed

Answer (score 0):

This program invokes **undefined behavior** because the format specification doesn't match the type of argument (`int` versus `char *`).

C99, 7.19.6.1 # 9 (fprintf)

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is
>   undefined.239) If any argument is not the correct type for the
>   corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

The correct way to print an address is with `%p` and via a `(void *)` argument:

```
printf("the address is: %p\n", (void *)ONE);
```